# Minimal polynomial of $\pi$ over a field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, pi, minimal-polynomials

This is a question from my past Qual exams.

"Determine the minimal polynomial of $\pi$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}((\pi^2+1)/(\pi-1))$."

I do not know how to approach this kind of problem. If the problem is find polynomial of $a$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ where $a,b$ are algebraic, I will solve it by taking $[\mathbb{Q}(a,b):\mathbb{Q}]/[\mathbb{Q}(b):\mathbb{Q}]$. Of course, this way is not effective here.

I read books of Dummit, Foote and Escofier. They do not mention this kind of problem.

Can you tell me how to approach this?

Comment: The only interesting part is the one that the answers chose to omit, proving that $\pi\notin\mathbb{Q}((\pi^2+1)/(\pi-1))$. Assume $\pi$ belongs to that field, then there is a rational function $R(x)$ with rational coefficients such that $\pi=R((\pi^2+1)/(\pi-1))$. Since $\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ it must happen that $x=R((x^2+1)/(x-1))$. Clearing the denominators $x-1$ in the right and letting $x\to1$ we get that the numerator and the denominator of $R(x)$ must have the same degree. This is a contradiction with the quotient being $x$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I disagree with your opinion that this claim is interesting, let alone the "only interesting part" of this question. If $\pi\in\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha=(\pi^2+1)/(\pi-1)$, then by definition that means $\pi=q_0+q_1\alpha+\cdots+q_n\alpha^n$ for some rationals $q_i$. Move everything over to one side to conclude that $\pi$ is a root of a rational polynomial, a contradiction of transcendentality. In particular no limit nor degree considerations are required.

Comment: @pre-kidney You have even more serious problems than I thought. The elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ are not polynomials on $\alpha$ with rational coefficients. They are rational functions on $\alpha$ with rational coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha=(\pi^2+1)/(\pi-1)$ and let $R=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$. Observe that $\pi$ is a root of the quadratic polynomial
$$
p(x)=x^2-\alpha(x-1)+1\in R[x].
$$
Thus, the minimal polynomial of $\pi$ (over $R$) divides $p(x)$. On the other hand, it is straightforward to show that $\pi\not\in R$, and thus the minimal polynomial of $\pi$ has degree greater than $1$, which implies that it equals $p(x)$.

Comment: thanks. I thought there would be a trick but clearly there is not

Comment: @MarcosGNeil There is, in proving that $\pi\notin \mathbb{Q}((\pi^2+1)/(\pi-1))$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy while I grant you that a "trick" is in the eye of the beholder, I personally do not see any trick in proving that claim. Indeed, suppose for contradiction that $\pi$ belongs to $ R$. Then one obtains a non-trivial rational polynomial (over $\mathbb Q$) with a $\pi$ as a root, hence a contradiction of transcendentality of $\pi$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: And again you are skipping the part where all the substance resides. That the polynomial that $\pi$ satisfies is non-trivial. Comes to show, that you were clearly bullshitting your way out of the answer when you wrote that 'it is straightforward'. Write that in my classes and you will get next to no marks for that.

Comment: I disagree entirely with your assessment and find it quite hostile, and I will disengage from this conversation in the interest of civility.

Comment: Well, at least study what is $\mathbb{Q}(x)$.

Comment: I guess that what @MoonLightSyzygy is concerned about is that a full answer should show an awareness of the difference between $\pi\in\Bbb{Q}((\pi+1)/(\pi-1))$ and $\pi\notin\Bbb{Q}((\pi^2+1)/(\pi-1))$. Just telling *it leads to a polynomial equation satisfied by $\pi$* does not capture that :-).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen And not just a polynomial, but a non-trivial polynomial equation needs to be proben to occur. $\pi$ has no problem satisfying the polynomial $0$. The condition that $\pi$ is in the field gives a rational function (which the person who gave this answer didn't know, but that's not even the point). That rational function could potentially be an identity. If instead of $\alpha=(\pi^2+1)/(\pi-1)$ it were just slightly different $\alpha=(\pi+1)/(\pi-1)$, then that would happen. In this case one would have $\pi=\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha-1}$ and $\pi$ would be in the field.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r=\frac {\pi^2+1}{\pi-1} $. By "undoing" this number you can get that  $$p (x)=r (x-1)-1-x^2$$ satisfies $p (\pi)=0$. It will be minimal if you see that the minimal polynomial cannot be of degree one, which amounts to say that  $\pi $ is not in your field.